# Can I write const expression double that is two ulps less than -0.5

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have a set of floating point calculation based on numbers I receive via a json packet. At the end of my calculation I require one of the numbers to be >= -0.5. I'm finding that sometimes I have a value that fails the test because it is one [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) below the threshold. Is there anyway to write a constexpression that means something like

```
constexpr auto threshold = -0.5 - 2*ULP;
```

or do I have to resort to something like

```
auto threshold = -0.5;
threshold = std::nexttoward(threshold, -2.0);
threshold = std::nexttoward(threshold, -2.0);
```

Comment: -0.5 is represented exactly in floating-point. Unclear why any approximation should be required.

Comment: try `constexpr auto threshold = -0.5f - 2.0f * std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();`' (c++11)

Comment: At the very least you can write this as `const auto threshold = nexttoward(nexttoward(-0.5));`

Comment: @ikleschenkov, I like that idea, but becuase epsilon is one ULP at 1.0, in this case it actually gives a value four ULPs below 0.5. If I take out the 2, it works in this case although it's not a very generic answer for any threshold value.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz -- make that an answer. It will, hopefully, squeeze out all those that play games with `epsilon`.

Comment: I'm confused. If the requirement is that the value be >= -0.5, why do you want to allow values that are less than -0.5?

Comment: @PeteBecker: A user chooses a value at the limit of the valid range. Some FP calculations are performed and the results are converted to a JSON string passed through a socket. The values are unpacked and more FP calculations are performed. FP calculations aren't exact and they sometimes produce a little round-off that pushes the value outside my valid range. I can't go back and tell the user to pick a valid value because he already did! So I want to handle this case without completely discarding the validation check.

Comment: @JohnGordon -- I was making a slightly snarky point about your statement that you "require one of the numbers to be >= -0.5" but that you really want a lower threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this can do it (it needs base 2 floating point representation, and it doesn't work for denormals):

```
constexpr double num = -0.5;
constexpr double threshold = num + 
          2.0 
        * (num < 0 ? -1 : 1) 
        * std::pow(2.0,
                   std::floor(std::log(std::abs(num)) / std::log(2.0))) 
        * std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

How does it work (I describe it with IEEE754 in mind)?

Epsilon means 1 ULP when a number is in the range of [1.0;2.0). We need to scale epsilon, so it always means 1 ULP. The scale is based on the exponent part of the floating point number. If the number is [1.0;2.0), then the scale must be 1. If the number is [2.0;4.0), then the scale must be 2, for [4.0;8.0), it must be 4, etc. So, we need to find the nearest, less-than-or-equal power of 2: it is `2^floor(log2(number))`. And we need to care of negative numbers, that's why the `abs` and `(num<0?-1:1)` in the formula.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it's a constexpr and works across different ranges of values.

Comment: I discovered while implementing this that a std::log2() function is now available (gcc 6.2.1). That cleans it up quite a bit if you replace std::log(std::abs(num))/std::log(2.0) with std::log2(std::abs(num))

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to achieve desired threshold with `epsilon`, something like

```
constexpr auto threshold = -0.5 - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

Possibly add `*2` if you think you really need it, though since `epsilon` is defined for value `1.0`, it might work out just right for you here for `0.5`.

---

Alternatively, just don't use it as `constexpr`. Unless it is some inner loop in some very performance sensitive code, the difference should be negligible:

```
const auto threshold = std::nexttoward(std::nexttoward( -0.5, -2.0), -2.0);
```

Comment: It's important to realize that std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() is _not_ the same as one ULP except around 1.0. If my threshold was -5.0 instead of -0.5, epsilon() would be less than one ULP and the threshold stays exactly equal to 5.0. In this case, the line you suggested gives me a value of two ULPs below -0.5 without having to multiply by two.

Comment: @JohnGordon: It is the same as one ULP in the range of [1.0;2.0) (considering IEEE754 format). So the first part of this answer isn't right.

Comment: @geza: Actually, the first part is correct because I asked for 2 ULPs and epsilon() is 2 ULPs at +/- 0.5, although I don't think that was intentional in the answer.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Yes, you're right. For some reason I thought that -0.5 is just an example, and you need a general solution.

Comment: @geza: I asked a specific question, but I would like a more general solution. Your answer is more general, but looking at it makes my eyes bleed just a little.

Comment: @JohnGordon: don't say that, it is not that ugly :) I've added a little description.

Comment: @JohnGordon I edited geza's answer a bit, maybe looking at it hurts a bit less now...